# Can any one say which database date format is this?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, datetime, sybase, mainframe

I have received below date format in one of the client text file.
This date belong to which database?

```
01OCT2000:00:00:00
```

Comment: This question has so many possibilities, It's virtually impossible to answer.

Comment: Could be anything.  It's more of a 'what format is this' instead of a 'what database is this'. RDBMSes can store dates/times in dozens of different ways.

Comment: I think the only possible answer to the title is "your client".

Answer (score 2):

From my knowledge of DBMS's, you can't tell.

This is because you can edit the format of your `datetime` within the database management system itself, and so it can be from any one of them.

For example, have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) - it shows SO MANY WAYS the date format could be saved, and that's the same for **all** database systems.

---

Asking 'which is this from' is like asking *'Which Apple came from which tree in the orchard'* - with there being dozens of trees, as well as dozens of orchards.

So, in conclusion, You simply can't tell from the information you've given i'm afraid.

**'Useful' Links:**

- [SyBase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc33820_1150/html/dbparm/CCJCEHBB.htm)
- [w3Schools convert() function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)
- [Converting using SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)